# PySpark and SQL : join and null values

Tags: python, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe consisting of two columns, each named input and target. These two are crossJoin of two single-column dataframes. Below is an example of how such dataframe would look like.

| input | target |
| --- | --- |
| A | Voigt. |
| A | Leica |
| A | Zeiss |
| B | Voigt. |
| B | Leica |
| B | Zeiss |
| C | Voigt. |
| C | Leica |
| C | Zeiss |

Then I have another dataframe which provides a number which describes relation between input and target column. However, it is not guaranteed that each input-target has this numerical value. For example, A - Voigt may have 2 as its relational value but A-Leica may have not have this value at all. Below is an example

| input | target | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Voigt. | 2 |
| A | Zeiss | 1 |
| B | Leica | 3 |
| C | Zeiss | 5 |
| C | Leica | 2 |

Now I want a dataframe that is congregate of these two that looks like this.

| input | target | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Voigt. | 2 |
| A | Leica | null |
| A | Zeiss | 1 |
| B | Voigt. | null |
| B | Leica | 3 |
| B | Zeiss | null |
| C | Voigt. | null |
| C | Leica | 5 |
| C | Zeiss | 2 |

I tried to join left these two columns, and tried to filter these out, but I've had problem completing in this form.

```
result = input_target.join(input_target_w_val, (input_target.input == input_target_w_val.input) & (input_target.target == input_target_w_val.target), 'left')
```

How should I put a filter from this point, or is there another way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using it as below -

**Input DataFrames**

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[("A","Voigt.") ,("A","Leica") ,("A","Zeiss") ,("B","Voigt.") ,("B","Leica") ,("B","Zeiss") ,("C","Voigt.") ,("C","Leica") ,("C","Zeiss")], schema = ["input", "target"])
df1.show()

+-----+------+
|input|target|
+-----+------+
|    A|Voigt.|
|    A| Leica|
|    A| Zeiss|
|    B|Voigt.|
|    B| Leica|
|    B| Zeiss|
|    C|Voigt.|
|    C| Leica|
|    C| Zeiss|
+-----+------+

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[("A","Voigt.",2) ,("A","Zeiss",1 ) ,("B","Leica",3 ) ,("C","Zeiss",5 ) ,("C","Leica",2 )], schema = ["input", "target", "val"])
df2.show()

+-----+------+---+
|input|target|val|
+-----+------+---+
|    A|Voigt.|  2|
|    A| Zeiss|  1|
|    B| Leica|  3|
|    C| Zeiss|  5|
|    C| Leica|  2|
+-----+------+---+
```

**Required Output**

```
df1.join(df2, on = ["input", "target"], how = "left_outer").select(df1["input"], df1["target"], df2["val"]).show(truncate=False)

+-----+------+----+
|input|target|val |
+-----+------+----+
|A    |Leica |null|
|A    |Voigt.|2   |
|A    |Zeiss |1   |
|B    |Leica |3   |
|B    |Voigt.|null|
|B    |Zeiss |null|
|C    |Leica |2   |
|C    |Voigt.|null|
|C    |Zeiss |5   |
+-----+------+----+
```

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer. Upvote too, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify a list of join column names.

```
df = df1.join(df2, ['input', 'target'], 'left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Some plagiarized modifications are completely silent. Not once or twice, and you take pride in constantly copying other people's work, don't you?

Forgive me for another post, I'm really pissed off, this kind of behavior has seriously disturbed the atmosphere of the forum.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not sure if I follow you here. Have I done something wrong ?

Comment: I'm very sorry to bother you, this is not for you. happy weekend!